# Mobile Jquery popup is not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I had spent 3 hours and go through many answers but not successful, I do't know where I am missing something

mobile jquery popup is not opened when i click the link here [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sulemanahmad/SaJgU/1/)

please any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQM does not have a popup feature yet. It is however a planned feature for JQM v 1.2. You may be interested in the Simple Dialog 2 plugin to provide that kind of functionality. http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/

Also on a side note. You are way off on your fiddle. You were including jQuery version 1.2.6 which is really outdated and wouldn't even work right with JQM. Another thing is that you didn't even have the css or js files required to make jQuery mobile work. I suggest you start with the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/) and **read** it. Check out the following link:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

Comment: might be not including the proper files in fiddle?

Comment: You definitely are not including jquery mobile.

Answer (score 4):

I see what's happened here.

if you google 'jquery mobile', the documentation link that comes up is actually a link to:
jquerymobile.com/test/

rather than:

jquerymobile.com/demos/

you can see the version and status of whatever you're looking at in the top right hand corner of the documentation page.

as codaniel said, popups are an upcoming feature in JQM v 1.2.

here's a fiddle linking to the 1.2 build that the /test/ site uses. NOTE: this is not officially supported - don't use it for release sites until a 1.2 final release is released.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncDbn/